# cassandra 3 throws Snitch class exception in debian docker container during startup

Tags: java, linux, cassandra, debian, cassandra-3.0

I am unable to start cassandra 3.0.9 on debian containers.

```
Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered    
during startup: Unable to find snitch class 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.GossippingPropertyFileSnitch'
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Unable to find snitch  
class 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.GossippingPropertyFileSnitch'
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.classForName(FBUtilities.java:480)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:513)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createEndpointSnitch(DatabaseDescriptor.java:747)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:446)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit> (DatabaseDescriptor.java:119)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:543)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:696)
```

I am using cassandra cluster of 3 nodes of which 2 are seed nodes.

I followed the below link:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/initialize/initSingleDS.html

Below is my OS:

```
root@2e8538746e9e:/etc/cassandra# uname -a
Linux 2e8538746e9e 4.4.39-moby #1 SMP Fri Dec 16 07:34:12 UTC 2016 x86_64    
GNU/Linux
root@2e8538746e9e:/etc/cassandra#
```

Any issues with installation or should i choose another snitch type?

Answer (score 2):

No, the GossipingPropertyFileSnitch should be fine, but you have an extra 'p'.

> Unable to find snitch class 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.Gossi**pp**ingPropertyFileSnitch'

Run this command, and make sure there's only one 'p' in "Gossiping."

```
$ grep endpoint_snitch cassandra.yaml 
# endpoint_snitch -- Set this to a class that implements
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

Correcting the name of the snitch in your cassandra.yaml file should fix this issue.